# Boot computer from a Windows XP VM Image?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualization, portable, bootloader

It seems as this isn't impossible but I haven't found any software that does this, except this one, but it isn't even released yet: [vBoot](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php/products/vboot).

**My objective is:**

- Install Windows XP in a VM and save it as an image.
- Put that image in a storage medium such as USB or disk.
- Boot an arbitrary machine directly on a VM that reads that image.
- (Optionally) save changes to the image before shutting down.

It's ok if I have to get used to new tools (up to date VirtualBox solved all my needs).

It's also ok if I have to deal with scripting, even some coding, or anything that can help me achieve that task, as it would be very useful to have a portable WinXP VM that I can *boot* into.

**In a nutshell: to run VirtualBox/VMWare/other XP image *without* booting into a preinstalled OS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted when I asked this answer, I've finally accomplished.

Here's what you do:

1. Create a VM in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Windows on it, set it up the way you want (update it too).
2. Image it, that is, create a [drive image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) to be used later.
3. "Restore" the image on your desired machine. Don't boot it, you'll simply get a BSOD.
4. Run any ["Universal Restore"](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=universal%20restore) kind of software(*). I've used Acronis'.
5. It boots, but it's not ready, unless you added drivers in the last step. Download and install each. If having problems figuring which drivers you need, use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

(*) The same thing can be [done with SysPrep](http://www.vernalex.com/guides/sysprep/), these solutions are just incredibly easier.

And that's it, basically booting a VM in a physical machine, for any purpose needed (fix somebody's computer no longer a pain) and streamlined in a process even your girlfriend will do with ease.

Answer (score 2):

That's systematically impossible on a Windows installation because of the anti-piracy measures, but barring that (say you miraculously got Microsoft to send you a version without any anti-piracy measures), what you're trying to accomplish can very well be done (check out the dated [Pendrive Linux Distro](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/run-pendrivelinux-2009-in-windows/#more-2154)). It's obviously a lot easier to do on Linux, because, of course, the lack of the aforementioned anti-piracy measures.

You may also want to look at raw disk booting. It provides the same end-result (being able to boot physically and on a VM). PendriveLinux has a [guide for that](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/) too. With this, you can probably set up a very nice BartPE setup (although BartPE has no persistence, i.e. settings changes aren't saved).

Comment: Well it supposedly **could** be done legally with a VLK... But anyway, I'll take a look at that :) Also, BartPE is very slow and has no Explorer Shell, right?

Comment: Now that I've look at it, seems it's not exactly what I want - to *boot into the VM*, not just run a portable VirtualBox... :(

Answer (score 0):

It's been done with Virtual box and grub4dos to get it to boot properly

Also some russian guy did it with a really hacky mess with registry entries and boot manager files

I need it to make use of some old laptops that vhave a busted hdd and cd. You csn search on keywords above to grab the links